# jQuery click function just shows first value on a page

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem with my jQuery code, I use "show" and "hide" buttons to display/hide the class, but jQuery only works with my first class. My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $(".menu_sub_index").hide(500);
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $(".menu_sub_index").show(500);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="danhmuc">
  <button id="hide">&#9940;</button>
  <button id="show">Category</button>
</div>
```

Any suggestions to improve my code? Thanks!

Comment: `id` have to be unique. Change to `class="hide"` and use `$('.hide')...`

Comment: Show your complete HTML

Comment: For more understanding kindly share your completed code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for your idea! after I change to class , it's nearly solve, the content in class menu_sub_item_index has been show but the button hide not display and when I click to show, all the area have class menu_sub_item_index are show...

Comment: This is my url: daunhotdongluc dot com.

Comment: My full code: https://notepad.pw/my7pm91r

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your html element to be as given below.

```
<div class="menu_sub_index">Div Content</div>

<div class="danhmuc">
  <button id="hide">&#9940;</button>
  <button id="show">Category</button>
</div>
```

Click function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $(".menu_sub_index").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $(".menu_sub_index").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but your code look like me! Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#hide").on("click", function(e){
    $(".menu_sub_index").hide();
   });

   $("#show").on("click", function(e){
    $(".menu_sub_index").show();
    });
});
<div class="danhmuc">
 <button id="hide">&#9940;</button>
 <button id="show">Category</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please explain your code, like how this code is different from the one posted by OP

Comment: The code is same but I have just added event delegation

Comment: So please explain those differences as well, that is helpful for others users as well.